# Selecting path (multiple records) where an ID number (fk) in a table references another ID number (pk) in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with ID numbers that reference old ID numbers (the foreign keys reference primary keys in the same table).  The problem I am having is there is an unknown number of records that need to be cycled through to get back to the original RecordID.  For example, the data might look like:

```
CategoryID | CategoryName | ParentCategory
-----------+--------------+---------------
1          | Books        | NULL
2          | Music        | NULL
3          | Hardcover    | 1
4          | Softcover    | 1
5          | Electronic   | 1
6          | CD           | 2
7          | MP3          | 2
8          | Rock         | 6
9          | Hard Rock    | 6
10         | Classic Rock | 6
11         | Fiction      | 3
12         | Fiction      | 4
13         | Non-Fiction  | 3
14         | Reference    | 13
15         | Biography    | 13
```

So, my result set needs to be something like:

```
Column A  |   Column B   |  Column C
----------+--------------+-------------
1         | Books        | [NULL]
2         | Music        | [NULL]
3         | Hardcover    | [Books]
4         | Softcover    | [Books]
5         | Electronic   | [Books]
6         | CD           | [Music]
7         | MP3          | [Music]
8         | Rock         | [CD, Music]
9         | Hard Rock    | [Rock, CD, Music]
10        | Classic Rock | [Rock, CD, Music]
11        | Fiction      | [Softcover, Books]
12        | Fiction      | [Hardcover, Books]
13        | Non-Fiction  | [Hardcover, Books]
14        | Reference    | [Non-Fiction, Hardcover, Books]
15        | Biography    | [Non-Fiction, Hardcover, Books]
```

...You get the idea.  I could have an infinite number of categories to loop through and need to show a path back to the first record with a null value.

I know I need some sort of case and loop on this, if exists, then select this, if exists then select next and probably have it mapped to an XML path but I am really struggling with the syntax and logic to make this happen.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When working with an **adjacency list** list like this, you will often need to use recursive [common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) like this:

```
;with cte as (
select
    t.*
  , Path = convert(varchar(128),CategoryName)
  , ParentPath = convert(varchar(128),null)
from t
where t.ParentCategory is null
union all 
select 
    c.*
  , [Path] = convert(varchar(128),p.Path + ', ' + c.CategoryName)
  , ParentPath = p.Path
  from t as c
    inner join cte p 
      on c.ParentCategory = p.CategoryID
    )
select 
    CategoryId
  , CategoryName
  , Path=quotename(ParentPath)
from cte
order by CategoryId
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/SSWK51498

returns:

```
+------------+--------------+---------------------------------+
| CategoryId | CategoryName |              Path               |
+------------+--------------+---------------------------------+
|          1 | Books        | NULL                            |
|          2 | Music        | NULL                            |
|          3 | Hardcover    | [Books]                         |
|          4 | Softcover    | [Books]                         |
|          5 | Electronic   | [Books]                         |
|          6 | CD           | [Music]                         |
|          7 | MP3          | [Music]                         |
|          8 | Rock         | [Music, CD]                     |
|          9 | Hard Rock    | [Music, CD]                     |
|         10 | Classic Rock | [Music, CD]                     |
|         11 | Fiction      | [Books, Hardcover]              |
|         12 | Fiction      | [Books, Softcover]              |
|         13 | Non-Fiction  | [Books, Hardcover]              |
|         14 | Reference    | [Books, Hardcover, Non-Fiction] |
|         15 | Biography    | [Books, Hardcover, Non-Fiction] |
+------------+--------------+---------------------------------+
```

References:

- [Sample chapter on Traversing Hierarchies - Sql Server Bible 2008](http://www.sqlserverbible.com/files/sqlserver2008bible_ch17.pdf)
- [Louis Davidson - Presentations - How to Optimize a Hierarchy In SQL Server - Presentations & Demo Code](http://www.drsql.org/Pages/Presentations.aspx)